# Why does Angular injector detect the following provided even if its not in the injector heirarchy?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-injector

From the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lightweight-injection-tokens), following is an example of `lightweight injection token` pattern for enabling tree shaking:

```
abstract class LibHeaderToken {}

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-header',
  providers: [
    {provide: LibHeaderToken, useExisting: LibHeaderComponent}
  ]
  ...,
})
class LibHeaderComponent extends LibHeaderToken {}

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-card',
  ...,
})
class LibCardComponent {
  @ContentChild(LibHeaderToken) header: LibHeaderToken|null = null;
}
```

My question is that when Angular sees `@ContentChild(LibHeaderToken)`, it will try to look for  a provider with token name as `LibHeaderToken`, but it'll look for it on the current component or its parents (because its an hierarchical injector). It'll not look in `LibHeaderComponent` (which is where we have declared the required provider).

So why does this work and why `LibHeaderComponent` is also searched when looking for providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for the definition of **@Contentchild** decorator, it's written in the original docs:

> The following selectors are supported.
>
> 1. Any class with the @Component or @Directive decorator
> 2. A template reference variable as a string (e.g. query <my-component
>    #cmp> with @ContentChild('cmp'))
> 3. Any provider defined in the child component tree of the current
>    component (e.g. @ContentChild(SomeService) someService: SomeService)
> 4. Any provider defined through a string token (e.g.
>    @ContentChild('someToken') someTokenVal: any)
> 5. A TemplateRef (e.g. query  with
>    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template;)

In the bullet list, the 3rd bullet says *"Any provider defined in the child component tree of the current component (e.g. @ContentChild(SomeService) someService: SomeService)"*. So in the example, *LibCardHeader* is in the child component tree of *LibCardComponent*, and the *LibHeaderToken* is a provider defined in the *LibCardHeader* -which is child component- which matches with the explanation "Any provider defined in the child component tree of the current component". The current component is *LibCardComponent*.

edit: [docs reference](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild)